# Multiple file upload using laravel and vue js error not print

Tags: laravel, validation, vue.js

Multiple file upload using vue js in laravel my validation is like

```
$request->validate([
        'title' => 'required',
        'pics.*' => 'required|image|mimes:jpeg,png,jpg,gif'
    ]);
```

and my component is like below

```
<template>
   <div class="col-md-6">
            <div class="form-group">
               <label>Title</label>
                <input id="title" type="text" ref="myDiv" v-model="title" class="form-control" name="title">
                <div v-cloak><label class="error" v-if="errors['title']">{{ errors.title[0]
                    }}</label></div>
            </div>

        </div>  
  <div class="col-md-6">
            <div class="form-group">
                <label>Upload Files</label>
                <input id="uploadfile" type="file" ref="pics" name="pics[]" multiple class="form-control" @change="fieldChange">
                <div v-cloak><label class="error" v-if="errors['pics']">{{ errors.pics[0] }}</label></div>
            </div>
        </div>  
</template>
export default {
    data(){
      return {
          attachments:[],
          pics : [],
          errors: [],
          form: new FormData
      }
    },
    methods:{
        fieldChange(e){
            let selectedFiles=e.target.files;
            if(!selectedFiles.length){
                return false;
            }
            for(let i=0;i<selectedFiles.length;i++){
                this.attachments.push(selectedFiles[i]);
            }
            console.log(this.attachments);            
        },
        uploadFile() {
            this.errors = [];
            this.form.append('img',this.attachments2);
            if(this.attachments.length > 0){
                for(let i=0; i<this.attachments.length;i++){
                    this.form.append('pics[]',this.attachments[i]);
                }
            }else {
                this.form.append("pics", '');
            }
            //this.form.append('')
            const config = { headers: { 'Content-Type': 
            'multipart/form-data' } };
          axios.post('/admin/theme/',this.form,config).then(response=> 
          { 
                this.pics = [];
            }).catch((error) => {
                this.errors = error.response.data.errors;
                console.log(this.errors.pics);

            });

        }
    }, 
    mounted() {
        console.log('Component mounted.')
    }
}
```

If i click to submit button empty title error print but multiple file error not print, i get error but not print

pics.0:["The pics.0 field is required."]

But title field validation error print perfectly

Please anyone help me to print multiple file upload error using vue js

Comment: You're only printing the first error `errors.title[0]`, loop the errors if you want to print them all.

Comment: this.errors = error.response.data.errors; is create errors array and print all errors , errors.title[0] print error but errors.pics[0] not

Comment: Laravel validation error return like this 

pics.0 : ["The pics.0 field is required."]
title:["The title field is required."]